# Is this technique necessary when using array_walk()

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on code that wasn't written by me. I see that the developer wanted to trim all elements of the array and used `array_walk()` but what's the point of declaring a `_trim` function that all it does is use the standard `trim()`?

```
array_walk($arr, '_trim');

function _trim(&$value)
{
    $value = trim($value);
}
```

Comment: So he could pass it by reference

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, for array_walk it would be necessary, because of call-by-reference. In this case it would be in my opinion better to use array_map:

```
$arr = array_map('trim', $arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Like the [manual](http://php.net/array_walk) says:

> If *funcname* needs to be working with the actual values of the array, specify the first parameter of *funcname* as a reference. Then, any changes made to those elements will be made in the original array itself.

It would perhaps be easier to use `array_map`:

```
$arr = array_map('trim', $arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use **anonymous function** to trim array elements. The advantage over `array_map` is that you can use `array_walk` **recursively**:

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function(&$v) {
    $v = trim($v);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`trim` returns a trimmed value, it doesn't modify the passed value.

array_walk($arr, 'trim');

if you execute array_walk with a normal trim you'll see that it doesn't do anything: